# Error with access control in yii2

Tags: yii2, access-control, rbac

I'm getting an error when trying to give some users access to a module

```
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;

     public function behaviors()
     {
    return [
       'access'=>[
            [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(), 
                'only'=>['view','index'],
                'rules'=>[
                    [    
                        'allow'=>true,
                        'actions'=>['view','index'],
                        'roles'=>['Administrador'],
                    ]
                 ],
                                ]
        ],
```

**Error message**

> Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an array too much there:

```
public function behaviors()
 {
return [
   'access'=>[
            'class' => AccessControl::className(), 
            'only'=>['view','index'],
            'rules'=>[
                [    
                    'allow'=>true,
                    'actions'=>['view','index'],
                    'roles'=>['Administrador'],
                ]
             ],
    ],
```